# How do I remove the Tab Bar from my Launch Screen Animation?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I have an application which copies the twitter loading screen animation, however, whenever my animation runs the tab bar is over the animation I think I need to update the view to the window instead of the view but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    splashView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 65/255, green: 204/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1.0)

    view.addSubview(splashView) //needs to be window if you haave tab bar
    splashView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
    logoImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    splashView.addSubview(logoImage)
    logoImage.frame = CGRect(x: splashView.frame.midX - 35, y: splashView.frame.midY - 35, width: 70, height: 70)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
        self.scaleDownAnimation()
    }
}
```

Also use scaleDownAnimation() scaleUpAnimation() and removeSplashScreen() functions.

Comment: It would be great if you could post enough of your code that we could see the context in which you are having this problem. There are a lot of details (not shown here) that could affect the answers that you'll get. Please try to put together a more complete post based on these guidelines [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeHay Apologies, adding more details.

Comment: @kmnflask You need to write assign root view controller code after complete the need of splash screen. maybe in **removeSplashScreen()**